# The Knockout way to apply a class to a specific button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, knockout.js

I have three buttons that are answers in a multiple choice exam simulator. I want to apply a red background color only to the clicked answer.  I have resolved the green color background logic for the right one.

I read that the right way is to do a data-bind click, change an observable, then apply a class to the button depending on its value, but I have three buttons, and if I do this in the three buttons the three are going to be red.

How can I do that in Knockout?

Comment: You don't "apply the class to the button", you bind the observable to the button. Each button will need a different observable, or possibly a function. Take a look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html
Also go through the Knockout tutorial if you haven't. http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: The three buttons should be bound to three different objects (or instances). So making one red shouldn't affect others.

Comment: Please, show the relevant code. This problem is really easy to solve, but it's necessary to see the exact structure of your buttons, and viewModel. What they've exaplined you is completely correct.